# How to pass a prop from parent directly to all children components?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

***Example:***

```
<parent-component :prop1="hello" :prop2="hello2">
</parent-component>
```

**parent-component.vue:**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <child1-component :obj1="prop1"></child1-component>
    <child2-component :obj2="prop2"></child2-component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {

  //code

};
</script>
```

*here I want to just pass these props (prop1, prop2 ) directly, without the need to write them inside the **parent-component** like this:

```
props: ["prop1", "prop2"],
```

Comment: if you want to use the props in your case passing it on to children you got to register them using `props` option.

Comment: @Vamsi Krishna, is there any other ways ? because, its too much to use props oprion inside the parent component, also use it inside child components ...

Comment: if there is too much nesting of component you can consider using a state management system like [vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/) or create a simple [state management](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/state-management.html#Simple-State-Management-from-Scratch) if your app is small

Comment: Look at the bottom half of my answer regarding `$attrs` and `inheritAttrs`, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47069902/vue-vuex-getter-vs-passing-state-via-props/47070436#47070436

Comment: @Eric Guan, that is what I was looking for.. you saved me!

Answer (score 0):

There is no way you can pass to all those children component without using either props or any kind of state management.

You can still simply manage all those state using the [Global Event Buss](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/). Global Event Bus is simple enough for your application if you don't want to use Vuex. In this case your `props1, props2` will be store globally and can access by your child of child components easily without using props.